# .env with React

Tags: reactjs, api

[image]every time I try to run my api call my key is undefined:
https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=undefined&dates=2022-04-03,2023-04-03&ordering=-rating&page_size=10

hHere is my api file:
const url = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=';

```
const getCurrentMonth = () => {
const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1
if (month < 10) {
    return `0${month}`
} else {
    return month
}
}

const getCurrentDay = () => {
const day = new Date().getDay()
if (day < 10) {
    return `0${day}`
} else {
    return day
}
}

const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const currentMonth = getCurrentMonth();
const currentDay = getCurrentDay();
const currentDate = `${currentYear}-${currentMonth}-${currentDay}`;
const lastYear = `${currentYear - 1}-${currentMonth}-${currentDay}`;
const nextYear = `${currentYear + 1}-${currentMonth}-${currentDay}`;

const popularGames = `&dates=${lastYear},${currentDate}&ordering=-rating&page_size=10`;
const upcomingGames = `games?dates=${currentDate},${nextYear}&ordering=-added&page_size=10`
const upcomingGameURL = () => `${url}${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}${upcomingGames}`
const popularGamesURL = () => `${url}${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}${popularGames}`;
console.log(popularGamesURL())
```

Here is my env file:
REACT_APP_API_KEY=bfd1ac5d55.........

File structure is in attached image

It was working api calls were successful but then it just stopped working?????
I have npm dotenv installed, i tried require('dotenv').config(); which works when console.log the api call, but when making the call with react app it causes another error.

Comment: Looks like in your terminal the api key = undefined, doesn't seem like it's being correctly interpreted...

Comment: You shouldn't be baking your API key into the client code anyway. That way it's shared with every user of the app.